# Default values of @ConfigurationProperties are not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot application I have a properties object with validations and  default values.

Consider this sample Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DummyApplication {

    @Validated
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dummy")
    public static class DummyProperties {

        @NotNull
        private String prop = "test";

        // getter, setter ...
    }

    @Component
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(DummyProperties.class)
    public static class DummyComponent {

        @Autowired
        public DummyComponent(DummyProperties properties) {
            Assert.notNull(properties.prop, "prop should have a value");

            // ...
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DummyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This worked with Spring Boot 1.4.x.

With Spring Boot 1.5.x and 2.0.x, I get an exception because `properties.prop` is null. But it shouldn't be null since I defined a default value above and didn't set a different value outside of my code.

It starts working again when I remove the `@Validated` annotation.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Replace `properties.prop` with `properties.getProp()`

### Reason

The annotation `@Validated` causes Spring to wrap the instance of DummyProperties with a proxy object.

The proxy object delegates all method calls to the underlying object, so getters and setters work as expected. But the proxy object doesn't delegate the field accesses, so the values of that proxy object are used. Unfortunately the field values are not copied from the underlying object, so the fields are initialized with null.

Comment: The fastest answer I have ever seen.

Comment: @Nikolas LOL it is a "question-answer" post. As you create a question you can post its answer too.